# $replaceRoot in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I use aggregation framework for group by of multiple fields as

```
{
_id:{_id:"$_id",feature_type:"$feature_type",feature_name:"$feature_name"},
features: { $push: "$features" }
}
```

it give result like

```
{_id:
     {_id:1,feature_type:"Test",feature_name:"Tests"},
  features:["23423","32423","2342342"]
}
```

but I want result like

```
{_id:1,feature_type:"Test",feature_name:"Tests",
  features:["23423","32423","2342342"]
}
```

how can i acheve this using aggregration framework.

Comment: use `$project` stage at the end of the pipeline something like this `$project:{_id:"$id._id"}` or use [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) at end of the pipeline

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet how to handle features key in $replaceRoot ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {      
      $project: {
                _id: "$_id._id",
                feature_type:"$_id.feature_type",
                feature_name:"$_id.feature_name",
                features:1
                }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 18):

You need to use [**`$replaceRoot`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to change your root document

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "_id.features": "$features"
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$_id"
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score -1):

use the project stage for reshaping the document at the end. return the only the desired field in which order you want.

```
project_stage = [{ "$project":{" _id": "$_id._id",
            "feature_type":"$_id.feature_type",
            "feature_name":"$_id.feature_name",
            "features": "$features"}
            }]
```

Comment: How is this different from the accepted answer?