# MongoDB - Remove parent array but keep child

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm struggling to find out how to project a result to remove the parent key, but keep the child array. In the example below map/project the array to remove the `notes` key.

I've tried all sorts of combinations but can't find my desired result and trawled through SO, and other sites.

The result array looking like:

```
[
    {
        "notes": {
            "createdBy": {},
            "systemCreate_DT": "2020-04-22T19:03:29+01:00",
        }
    },
    {
        "notes": {
            "createdBy": {},
            "systemCreate_DT": "2020-04-22T23:44:57+01:00",
        }
    }
  ]
```

I would like the result to look like this:

```
[
    {
      "createdBy": {},
      "systemCreate_DT": "2020-04-22T19:03:29+01:00",
    },
    {
      "createdBy": {},
      "systemCreate_DT": "2020-04-22T23:44:57+01:00",
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Try [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)....................

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$replaceRoot in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51298993/replaceroot-in-mongodb) , Test : (https://mongoplayground.net/p/3idoJ3ZQ3O2)

Comment: Perfect Solution